# Linux Centos - 'ls -d' command won't list folders

Tags: linux, permissions, ls

So I think I have a little user right issue.
Have been scripting a Webserver Control panel.

At a point in this script I'm listing all folders for a user into an array so I can compare it to the user input. (Each user is a new customer, and each customer can have multiple sites).
Up until Friday last week when I ran this command:

```
[rjo@WEB ~]$ sudo ls -d /home/hejhej/*/ 2>/dev/null
```

Everything was working fine running the command from my own user (rjo). But now when I run the command nothing happens, so I removed "2>/dev/null" and tried again and now I'm getting this:

```
[rjo@WEB ~]$ sudo ls -d /home/hejhej/*/
ls: cannot access /home/hejhej/*/: No such file or directory
```

But when running it from root everything works fine:

```
[root@WEB ~]# ls -d /home/hejhej/*/
/home/hejhej/bumbum.dk/
```

Here's the line regarding my user from visudo file.

```
rjo     ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If you need any other info to help pleas tell me and I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if your user doesn't have enough permissions on `/home/hejhej` to list its contents.

When you run:

```sh
sudo ls -d /home/hejhej/*/
```

It is *your* shell that tried to do filename globbing. If it can't read that directory, it can't expand anything. So the literal string `/home/hejhej/*/` is left as is, and passed as an argument to the `ls` run by `root` via `sudo`. It appears you don't have a directory called `*` in that directory, so `ls` fails.

You need the shell started by `sudo` to do the globbing here. One option might be:

```sh
sudo sh -c 'ls -d /home/hejhej/*/'
```

If you want the folder to search to contain a shell variable, then the `'` hard quotes won't do - this prevents your shell from globbing (good) but also prevents variable expansion by your shell (bad here). You should use double-quotes (`"`) instead so that variable expansion is done by your shell:

```sh
sudo sh -c "ls -d /home/$username/*/"
```

If you want to capture the ouput of that command into a variable, prefer the `$()` form of command substitution rather than backticks (`` ` ``) - easier for quoting:

```sh
result=$(sudo sh -c "ls -d /home/$username/*/")
```

Now if `$username` can contain spaces (say `username="hello world"`), what is above won't work - the root shell will see two "tokens" (`/home/hello` and `world/*/`). You can fix that with another layer of quotes:

```sh
result=$(sudo sh -c "ls -d /home/'$username'/*/")
```

Given how the quotes are nested, this will not prevent your shell from expanding `$username`, but will enable the root shell to glob correctly on the single pattern `/home/hello world/*/`.

Now, this is still not perfect. You'll have a hard time dealing with issues if that glob matches more than one directory, or if the directory matched contains spaces. But at this point I'd advise you to:

- Read this advice: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- Make a proper script run by root to handle finding the appropriate directory - one-liners are fine if they're short and easy to read. Once things get too complex, writing a proper script is a win in the long run.

That being said, if you want a list of directories from another user's home into an array, the following (bash specific I think) should do it, without the problems of parsing `ls`, and should handle spaces in files and directories:

```sh
while read -r -d $'\0' dir ; do
  array+=("$dir")
done < <(sudo find "/home/$username" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0)
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed it and you gave a good explanation to a beginner like me. Have been scripting and working with linux for 2 weeks now, so the information is appreciated.

Comment: Okay i have tried everything (i think) and i can't get it to work.        
domainFolders=\`sudo sh -c 'ls -d /home/$username/*/ 2>/dev/null'`
        It can't call the VAR $username, and i can't find a good site that explain the different symbols to use

Comment: @Rasmus J.: add some more info.

Comment: I'm trying to list all folders from a users home directory into an array (no sub-folders). I want to do it from my own account, as i use it to administrate all users and sites on this server. when i do it now i get all folders, but all in index 0. I want all folders it find, to have separate index number.
So when i echo index 0 it will display the first folder, echo index 1 displays the 2'nd folder and so on.